# Shared array for big data

Tags: c++

I have two threads. The first one is writing data from a USB in a big array(main buffer). Every when it gets new data from USB, an offset (write offset) will increase. In second thread has a "read offset" and it will grow (too) when new data are extracting from the main buffer.

One thread is writing, and the next is reading from that.

But this solution is not optimized. I'll need a big and bigger array for my different requirements. I need a dynamic behavior for using a memory that is shared between two or more threads.

I'm sure so many useful algorithms for my problem.

Anybody can suggest some of them, please? [C(++) language]

Comment: Do you know how to use `std::deque`? It'll likely manage your buffering much better than you can do yourself. All you have to do is make sure that access to the `std::deque` is properly synchronized between your execution threads.

Comment: thanks. let me check the std::deque. It seems good.

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar in C++. I started by building a list -- a free list -- of buffers, and populating it with two empty buffers I got from `malloc()` or `new`. Then my incoming data thread did this

1. if an empty buffer was in the list, take it off the list and start writing to it. If no buffers were in this list, I got another one from `malloc()` or `new`.
2. when the active buffer filled up, I put it into a queue and grabbed another.
3. my consumer thread, the other one, pulled buffers from the queued, did what was needed, and placed the buffer back in the free list.

This scheme worked better than the ring buffer scheme you described, because it could add buffers if needed.

You'll need to use thread-safe operations when you put buffers into the queue or the free list, or take them out. Use appropriate thread safe stdlib collections for the queue and the free list.

You could also use a ring buffer, and when it's not big enough use `realloc` to get a new one 1.5x the size and copy your data.

Comment: the @Sam Varshavchik  method is easier. let me chack that first.